# javac in command line with libraries and multiple files

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I always used Eclipse to create complex java programs, but a single one is being tricky to solve:

javac -cp ../../mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar:../../commons-cli-1.2-sources.jar *.java

I have some java classes on that directory and those java libraries to be ran with it.
when I run javac, it creates the .class files for me.
Now, when I run 
java DbTool I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DbTool (wrong name: tool/DbTool)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: DbTool.  Program will exit.

any help?

Comment: What si the folder structure of your source code and which directory are you in while firing the 'javac' command?

Comment: You are including the same classpath when you run the DbTool, as when you compiled it, right? Your class would still need access to these classes at runtime, just as it did at compile time

Comment: Be sure to look at using a build tool like Maven or Ant. You're working too hard! Make the computer do the compilation!

Comment: exabrial - I agree with you, I should be using maven or ant for that ...
Amit - I'll provide more details about the dir structure later tonight!